# Spring Security: Getting oauth2 token from authorization server using secret jwt client authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am trying to go through spring security 6 and set up oauth2. To get a token i am trying to use the `client_secret_jwt` authentication mechanism for client.
But after a lot of tries I have been unable to do so.

This is my code for registering client:

```
@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient registeredClient =
            RegisteredClient
                    .withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .clientId("client")
                    .clientSecret("secret_secret_secret_secret_secret")//.tokenSettings()
                    .clientAuthenticationMethod(
                            ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_JWT)
                    .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                            .tokenEndpointAuthenticationSigningAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)
                            .jwkSetUrl("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/jwks")
                            .build())
                    .authorizationGrantType(
                            AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                    .redirectUri("https://www.manning.com/authorized")
                    //.clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().build())
                    .scope("CUSTOM")
                    .build();

    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
}
```

This is my code for generating a jwt token signed using the secret key defined above.

```java
@Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource()
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        /* A different method */

        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        try {
            //printing a token at startup
            String assertion = getJWTToken("client");
            logger.info("Created assertion: "+assertion);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Error creating assertion: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private String getJWTToken(String username) {
        //using the secret key
        String secretKey = "secret_secret_secret_secret_secret";

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .subject(username)
                .issuer(username)
                .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .audience().add("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token").and()
                .issuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .expiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 600*1000))
                .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))).compact();

        return token;
    }
```

I am using the assertion printed at the start to call the token api, but have been unable to acquire a token after trying a gazillion variations.

This is the curl call i think is the one i am supposed to use

```bash
curl -X POST -v\
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjbGllbnQiLCJpc3MiOiJjbGllbnQiLCJqdGkiOiIxMjI0NmM4ZC0xZmIxLTRkM2UtODI2NC05OWRhNmYzNTA1NGIiLCJhdWQiOlsiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL29hdXRoMi90b2tlbiJdLCJpYXQiOjE3MDc2MzM0ODcsImV4cCI6MTcwNzYzNDA4N30.eYk7T67ue4KrqZqf3Rk06HqwEPRRXpYGSzkbWXtv7zo" \
  http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token
```

This is the response i keep getting

```bash
*   Trying [::1]:8080...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080
> POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 406
>
< HTTP/1.1 400
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sun, 11 Feb 2024 06:39:31 GMT
< Connection: close
<
{"error":"invalid_request"}* Closing connection
```

I am not sure what i am missing or doing wrong. Have not been able to find any example on the internet.

I have been able to get the credentials using both basic and post secret methods.

Edit---
Dug some more and found that there is an exception while client authentication

```
Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJOSEException: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:357) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.37.3.jar:9.37.3]
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:303) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.37.3.jar:9.37.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:158) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    ... 126 common frames omitted
```

I am definitely missing some configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after putting almost the whole day on it, i was able to obtain the token.

2 changes:

1. Provide the same algorithm as the one used for signing key using the secret.

```java
.clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                                .tokenEndpointAuthenticationSigningAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HS256)//not rs256
                                .jwkSetUrl("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/jwks")
                                .build())
```

2. Make sure client id is given in the token request. Even though it is optional, the Spring library requires it.

```
curl -X POST -v  -H \
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"\
-d "client_id=client&grant_type=client_credentials&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjbGllbnQiLCJpc3MiOiJjbGllbnQiLCJqdGkiOiIxNDdlMTU5YS05YjU3LTQ4NWMtYTM5Ni1hYzAxOGMyOThmZDkiLCJhdWQiOlsiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL29hdXRoMi90b2tlbiJdLCJpYXQiOjE3MDc2NDk2OTEsImV4cCI6MTcwNzY1NTY5MX0.J8G_luq7SMCbyaK_ykRtYdc9h-xEJhyi4RRTuH15w7I" \
http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token
```

Comment: `Even though it is optional` im curious, never heard it is optional do you have a source for that statement, also HS256 is _symmetric_ meaning that you use the same key to sign as to verify. This is usully not recommended because if one key leaks, it can be used to both sign and verify JWTs. Its  preferred to use RS256 which is _asymmetric_ so one service has the private key, and all the others have public keys.

Comment: @Toerktumlare It is specified by OIDC specification, as well as signing of the token using symmetric keys [Link](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClientAuthentication) . If we want asymmetric encryption, then the client authentication method used is private_key_jwt. You can also consult the spring source [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/web/authentication/JwtClientAssertionAuthenticationConverter.java) (line 73)

Comment: @Toerktumlare, yeah the client_id parameter on the token endpoint is optional. Very often you have different forms of authentication on that endpoint (e.g. Basic Auth or the client assertion used here) and you don't need that parameter. It's interesting that Spring requires it.

Comment: @Vaibhav Toerktumlare's comments on the signing algorithm are valid. If possible, don't use symmetric signing. Ideally, your client should have a private key that you sign with, and the OAuth server should only have access to the public key, to verify the JWT. I know that the spec allows you to use symmetric signing but its use is discouraged. Also — currently in your configuration, you don't need to specify the jwks URL is you're using symmetric signing.

Comment: Didnt know it was specified as optional, interesting, learnt something new today. Thank you.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski I am aware symmetric encryption isn't the most secure option available. This was just me trying to make it work, since all the guides available on the internet use even more vulnerable basic authentication for clients.

Comment: Symmetric signing (it's not encryption, it's signing) is pretty much as secure as basic auth. Both the client and the server need to know the same secret (as in basic auth). The difference would be when you have a man-in-the-middle attack. With a signed JWT the attacker won't automatically know the key. However, you should use a TLS connection to the server anyway, so an MITM attack is quite difficult.